# Select element with particular data attributes with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

How can I select element with particular data attribute and special class with jQuery please ?

For example, I would like to select these elements:

```
<div data-roomid="55" data-status="NoData"></div>
<div data-roomid="55" data-status="Open"></div>
<div data-roomid="55" data-status="Close"></div>
```

But not this one:

```
<div data-roomid="55" data-status="Book"></div>
```

My try is the following one:

```
roomid = 55;
$('[data-roomid="'+ roomid +'"]').each(function(e) {

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is a `special class`?  The term `class` has special meaning in html, so it's a bit confusing what you want.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute

Comment: One of the divs you want to select is identical to one you don't.

Comment: @kukkuz: good catch. Updated.

Comment: @j08691, correct. Changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:not` selector - see demo below:

```js
var roomid = 55, status = 'Book';
$('[data-roomid="' + roomid + '"]:not([data-status=' + status + '])').each(function() {
  $(this).css({
    color: 'blue'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-roomid="55" data-status="NoData">NoData</div>
<div data-roomid="55" data-status="Open">Open</div>
<div data-roomid="55" data-status="Close">Close</div>
<div data-roomid="55" data-status="Book">Book</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$('div:not([data-status=Book])[data-roomid='+ roomid +']')
```