# jquery attribute selector is not working for data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I know it could be duplicate of SO questions
[Selecting element by data attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute) and  [jQuery how to find an element based on a data-attribute value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value)

But still I am not able to select all elements where an attribute "data-value"  exist.

**Issue :**
I am expecting statement B)  `$('[data-value]')` or `$('*[data-value]*')` should return all elements which
have data attribute "data-value", but it  returns nothing.

However statement  A) `$('#openingBalAccount').data('value')` getting result "ACC-2".

If statement A above works, then statement B should also work, but its not happening.

Below is the Chrome Dev Tool screen for the same, consider first 2 statements in screen as Statement A above, and rest as Statement B. As stated above if statement A works,statement B also should work.

[image]

Dev Tool example should be more than sufficient to identify any issue, but if you still insist for the code, here it is.

**Jquery Statement to set data-value**

```
$('#accountsModalSelect').on('click', function onAccountsModalSelect() {
    let rowData = $('#accountsModalSelect').data('selected')
    if (rowData) $('.accountSource').val(rowData.description).data('value', rowData.account)
    $('#accountsModal').modal('hide')
})
```

**HTML Code in pug format**

```
                    form#openingBalForm
                        input.form-control#openingBalUpdateType(type='hidden')
                        input.form-control#formtab(type='hidden' value='openingbaltab')
                        .row.form-group
                            .col-4
                                labal(for='openingBalFinYear') Financial Year
                            .col
                                input.form-control#openingBalFinYear(name='openingBalFinYear' type='text' )
                        .row.form-group
                            .col-4
                                labal(for='openingBalAccount') Account
                            .col
                                .input-group
                                    input.form-control.accountSource#openingBalAccount(name='openingBalAccount' type='text' )
                                    .input-group-append#openingBalAccountSearch
                                        .input-group-text
                                            .fas.fa-search
                        .row.form-group
                            .col-4
                                labal(for='openingBalAmount')  Amount
                            .col
                                input.form-control#openingBalAmount(name='openingBalAmount' type='number')
```

Comment: If it's not in your HTML, then jQuery's `.data()` will not set an HTML `data-*` attribute. It will just store the data. If you want to set a `data-*` attribute, you need `.attr('data-whatever', '12345');`

Comment: As above, put another way:  `$().data("key", "value")` will store that value *internally* to jquery, it will not change your HTML, so looking for `$("[data-key=value]")` will not find it.  You could use .filter if there's some other selector option, eg something like  `$(".class").filter(function() { $(this).data("key") == "value"; })`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - thanks it did worked, as per your suggestion I included it in html, pug html look like now `(name='openingBalAccount' type='text' data-value='')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something like this, you also have to add the html-attribute to the element. You can't access the internal stored data.

```js
$('#accountsModalSelect').on('click', function onAccountsModalSelect() {
    let rowData = $('#accountsModalSelect').data('selected')
    if (rowData) {
        $('.accountSource')
            .val(rowData.description)
            .data('value', rowData.account)
            .attr('data-value', rowData.account) // Add this
    }
    $('#accountsModal').modal('hide')
})
```

Comment: thanks - it did worked, added to html code like `(name='openingBalAccount' type='text' data-value='')`