# Angular Unit Test: Query HTML Element by Data-QA Tag Attribute

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I am writing Angular unit tests, and want to query/get value of custom textbox by `data-qa` attribute per e.g. https://dev.to/chriszie/data-qa-attribute-a-better-way-to-select-elements-for-ui-test-automation-48lm.

How can this be done?

```html
 <app-textbox
    type="text"
    data-qa="productname"
 >
 </app-textbox>
```

```js
describe('ProductComponent', () => { 
  let component: ProductComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProductComponent>;


it('test value', () => {
   let data = fixture.debugElement.query(By  -- (not sure what to write here)
});
```

Comment: You can use CSS selectors for arbitrary attributes, including data- ones: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: hi @jonrsharpe feel free to write in code in answer, and I can send points, thanks

Comment: I'd suggest *actually trying it*, then you can [edit] to show a specific problem if you still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this and If this is not suffice, you can find more examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute)

```
it('test value', () => {
   const input = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[data-qa="productname"]')) 
   OR
   const input = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('input[data-qa="productname"]')
   console.log(input)
});
```