# How to get to attribute value using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following problem

```
<a href='#' data-entry-id='{{ income.incSum }}' id='some_link_1'></a>
```

```
const $entryElements = $('[data-entry-id]');

     const $entryIds =
         $.map($entryElements, item => $(item).data('entryId'));
     console.log("entry ids ", $entryIds);
```

If the data-entry-id attribute is in square brackets, everything works, the values are displayed.

Only I would like to get to the value of the data-entry-id attribute whose id is some_link_1 (because I have several data-entry-id values on the page):

```
<a href="#" data-entry-id="{{ income.incSum }}" id="some_link_1"></a>
```

I use the following notation for this:

```
const $entryElements2 = $('#some_link_1').attr('[data-entry-id]');
const $entryIdsEle = $.map($entryElements2, item => $(item).data('entryId'));
console.log("mine is: ", $entryIdsEle);
```

If data-entry-id is in square brackets, the values are empty, but if it is without brackets:

```
const $entryElements2 = $('#some_link_1').attr('data-entry-id');
```

an error occurs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC1xc.jpg)

Please help me how I could get to this data using attribute and id name.

I used this article https://cruftlesscraft.com/passing-data-from-twig-to-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting element by data attribute with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487747/selecting-element-by-data-attribute-with-jquery)

Comment: FYI: Your question has nothing to do with `twig`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Only I would like to get to the value of the data-entry-id attribute whose id is some_link_1 

// This selector should get the element with the id of `some_link_1` if it also has an attribute `data-entry-id`;

const $entryElements3 = $('#some_link_1[data-entry-id]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, that work for me:

```js
let els = $('a[data-entry-id]');

console.log(els);
    
els.map((key, el) => {
  console.log(el);
});
    
let el1 = els.filter((key, el) => $(el).attr('id') === 'some_link_1');
    
console.log(el1);
```

Comment: `$(el).attr('id')` -> `el.id`